# Delay ajax request before their resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a serie of ajax request which are all waited to be resolved before continuing
(achieved with `$.when().then()`):

```
function myfunc(offset) {
    // setTimeout(function(){
        return $.ajax({
            url:"https://www.URL.com",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (response) {
                // console.log(response);
                data = data.concat(response);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // handle errors
            } 
        });
    // },offset/10);-
}

$.when( // call all ajax requests
    myfunc(0)
    ,myfunc(2500)
    ,myfunc(5000)
    ,myfunc(7500)
    ,myfunc(10000)
    ,myfunc(12500)
    ,myfunc(15000)
    ,myfunc(17500)
    )
.then(function() { // when all the ajax requests are terminated
    console.log(data);
});
```

I would like to delay them a little bit to make it "more likely" that they end in some order.
(Cf. commented setTimeout in the code above).

> I don't want to execute the first ajax request and then the second and then the third. They should just start with ~250ms delays one from another.

But my attempt only results in the promise to be resolved immediately, without the ajax request being completed and thus an empty data.

Is there a way to set a timeout and don't loose the wait for the ajax resolution? Or should I structure my code differently?

Comment: If it doesn't matter what order the requests are processed, why delay everything by 250ms? Surely it either makes a difference, so you need to chain the requests, or it doesn't, and you can send them all at once.

Comment: Really looks like a XY problem. Is your goal to run requests sequentially or what?

Comment: If you want to do them sequentially you could just run the next one in .then(resolve) after each $.ajax() request.  I have to say, I think whatever you are doing it sounds like you are probably going about it the wrong way (or making it much more difficult than it should be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Like Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411469/delay-ajax-request-before-their-resolution/35411539#comment58523685_35411469) I'm a bit skeptical about the usefulness of doing it, but if you want to do it, you'd do it by returning your own promise that you resolve in the `ajax` callback:

```
function myfunc(offset) {
    var d = $.Deferred();                      // Create "Deferred" object
    setTimeout(function(){
        return $.ajax({
            url:"https://www.URL.com",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (response) {
                // console.log(response);
                data = data.concat(response);
                d.resolve();                   // Resolve it
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // handle errors
                d.reject();                    // Reject it
            } 
        });
    },offset/10);
    return d.promise();                        // Return its promise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above code and what it looks like you are doing (joining a bunch of responses in a specific order)... you could try something like below instead:

```js
urlArr = [
  "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
  "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"
];

function joinResponses(arr) {
  var promises = arr.map(function(url) {
    return $.ajax(url).then(function(res) {
      return JSON.stringify(res);
    });
  })
  return $.when.apply($,promises).then(function() {
    var joined = "";
    for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length;i++) {
      joined += arguments[i];
    }
    return joined;
  });
}

joinResponses(urlArr).then(function(myJoinedResponses) {
  document.write(myJoinedResponses);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Based on what you are asking for though it sounds rather strange and it seems like you could be doing something better.

Answer (score -1):

Rory point is very good, but in case you want to do it anyway.. I'd do something like that.

```
var arrayFunc = [func1, func2, func3]

for (var i = 0; i < arrayFunc.length; i++) {
  (function() {
    var j = i;
    setTimeout(() => {
      arrayFunc[j]();
    }, i * 2500);
  })();
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v78xv68a/2/#&togetherjs=E651TqcC8I)

---

edit: setTimeout function
edit2: Fixed the closure error

Comment: Ok I see. I had a closure error. It is now fixed and working.